# Xcode: Loading TabBarItem titles after ordering

Tags: xcode4, uitabbaritem

I'm using this [[tutorial](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-uitabbarcontroller-how-to-save-user-customized-tab-order)] to save user's customized TabBarItems order as my app has more than 5 tabs

The tutorial's concept is to save the TabBarItem titles in the NSUserDefault and load them next time app is opened.

It's working great for english language as my TabBarItem titles are set initially in the XIB file

But the problem is that when my app's other language is loaded, as TabBarItem titles are changed to the selected language upon starting the app

Thus when the titles got saved after re-ordering the TabBarItems for the language that is different than the titles set in the XIB file, the TabBarItem are not loaded at all next time the app started! Which I think the tutorial I used is only work for TabBarItem titles when they are identical to TabBarItem titles defined in XIB file, not when those TabBarItem titles got changed programmatically based on the app language!

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
  NSMutableArray *savedOrder = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tabController.viewControllers.count];
  NSArray *tabOrderToSave = tabController.viewControllers;
  for (UIViewController *aViewController in tabOrderToSave) {
    [savedOrder addObject:aViewController.tabBarItem.title];
  }
  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:savedOrder forKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [self setTabOrderIfSaved];
}

- (void)setTabOrderIfSaved {
  NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  NSArray *savedOrder = [defaults arrayForKey:@"savedTabOrder"];
  NSMutableArray *orderedTabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:tabController.viewControllers.count];
  if ([savedOrder count] > 0 ) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [savedOrder count]; i++) {
      for (UIViewController *aController in tabController.viewControllers) {
        if ([aController.tabBarItem.title isEqualToString:[savedOrder objectAtIndex:i]]) {
          aController.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(aController.tabBarItem.title, nil);
          [orderedTabs addObject:aController];
          }
        }
     }
     tabController.viewControllers = orderedTabs;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `tabBarItem`'s tag property instead.

```
aController.tabBarItem.tag
```